# Cannot create information with "" with php fwrite

Tags: php, html

I want to create a logout system where the user clicks a logout link and goes to logout.php . The logout link is in the user page that is created with fwrite when a new user is registered.

I have tried changing

```
<a href="logout.php"></a>
```

to

```
<a href=""logout.php""></a>
```

But that resulted in the link not showing up.

--------------------------------HERE IS MY CODE-------------------------------------------------------------

```
$myfile = fopen("user/$username.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$content = "

<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php 

session_start();

?>

<html>

<head>


<title>Vurzin</title>


</head>

<body>


<h2>Welcome $username !</h2>

<br><br><br><a href="logout.php"></a>


</body>


</html>";
fwrite($myfile, $content);
fclose($myfile);
header("Location: user/$username.php");
```

Comment: `\"logout.php\"` but wait wait wait are you creating a copy of the PHP file for every single user of your site? Mate, that's *not* how you do that XD Not to mention I could just navigate to `example.com/user/Vack Guy.php` and get your stuff.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                       
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////O.K. Three things. 1. Thank you for your help. 2. I have tried changing <a href=\"logout.php\"></a> but the link doesn't show up. 3. How could I make it so that only the user that is logged in is able to change the content of their page?

Comment: For `2`, do you actually have any text in the link? Because without text there's nothing to click on. For `3`, you really want to rethink your entire project. You should have a database, and pull data from it based on who's logged in, and use that to build your page.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol    Your solution did work for #2. I just forgot to put text  in the link. Whoops. //////////////////////////////////// #3, So when the user registers, I put their information inside the database and then when a user logs in with a username and password combination that matches a username and password combination that's inside the database it takes them to to their user profile. How could I make it so that if a user is logged in their able to edit their profile but if someone that's not logged goes to their profile page they can't edit the user's profile page?